# Haskell Partitions of a number

Tags: haskell

I'm Trying to create a program that finds every paritions of a number.

For example the ways to decompose 4 are:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 2]
[4]
```

I've done it in Python with:

```
n = 4
x = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
t = [0 for i in range(n+1)]
x[0] = 1

def partition(i):
    for j in range(x[i-1], (n - t[i-1])//2 + 1):
        x[i] = j
        t[i] = t[i-1] + j
        partition(i+1)

    x[i] = n - t[i-1]
    print(x[1:i+1])

partition(1)
```

But i need to write it in Haskell. Is there any way?

Comment: These are called [partitions](https://oeis.org/A000041) for what it's worth

Comment: oh thanks, my English is not too good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

It will be valuable to reverse the order while thinking about this, so you are trying to generate:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 1]
[4]
```

So, first choose every possible first element, here 1, 2, 3, or 4.  Say we've chosen 1, then there are 3 remaining.  We can recursively compute all the partitions of 3, and then prepend 1 to each of them.

(Oh, that's not quite right!  Still a good place to start.  But you will have e.g. `[1,2,1]` generated, so you will need to add a parameter, I think, saying "don't generate any numbers greater than `m`")

And we have to make sure to get the base case right.  How many partitions are there of 0?  There is one, the empty partition!

Answer (score 0):

You can also translate it very literally using mutable vectors. The main difference is that you need to separate reads and writes very explicitly in Haskell, so it becomes a bit more messy.

This is what I came up with without understanding your algorithm:

```
import Data.Foldable ( for_ )
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let n = 4
  x <- M.replicate (n + 1) 0
  t <- M.replicate (n + 1) 0
  M.write x 0 1
  let partition i = do
        x' <- M.read x (i - 1)
        t' <- M.read t (i - 1)
        for_ [x' .. (n - t') `quot` 2] $ \j -> do
            M.write x i j
            t' <- M.read t (i - 1)
            M.write t i (t' + j)
            partition (i + 1)
        t' <- M.read t (i - 1)
        M.write x i (n - t')
        x' <- V.freeze (M.slice 1 i x)
        print (V.toList x')
  partition 1
```